# How to loop over all elements of different sorted lists in sorted order?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, loops

I have several sorted lists. How can I loop over all elements in sorted order efficiently and elegantly? In my real-life problem, those lists contain elements that are directly comparable and sortable but are different and require different treatment.

I prefer to retain my lists, which is why I copy them manually. If that is missing from a one-liner solution like a library function, I will gladly use that and copy the lists beforehand.
This code does what I want but is neither efficient nor elegant.

```
from random import randint

a: list = []
b: list = []
c: list = []

list_of_lists: list = [a, b, c]

for i in range(10):
    l = randint(0, 2)
    list_of_lists[l].append(i)

print(a, b, c)
a_copy = a.copy()
b_copy = b.copy()
c_copy = c.copy()

# print the elements of the lists in sorted order
x = a_copy.pop(0)
y = b_copy.pop(0)
z = c_copy.pop(0)

while (x and x is not 1000) or \
        (y and y is not 1000) or \
        (z and z is not 1000):
    if x is not 1000 and x < y and x < z:
        print(x)
        if a_copy and a_copy[0]:
            x=a_copy.pop(0)
        else:
            x = 1000
    elif y is not 1000 and y < x and y < z:
        print(y)
        if b_copy and b_copy[0]:
            y=b_copy.pop(0)
        else:
            y = 1000
    elif z is not 1000 and z < x and z < y:
        print(z)
        if c_copy and c_copy[0]:
            z=c_copy.pop(0)
        else:
            z = 1000
```

Comment: This question may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You should almost certainly use `x != 1000` instead of `x is not 1000`.

Comment: @colidyre Based on the fact that there are multiple answers here and one has been accepted as well as the fact that the OP would have to post the real code on Code Review this question belongs here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, easiest and quite efficient is to actually just concatenate the list and sort them.

```
l = [*a, *b, *c] # alternatively, list(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
l.sort()
```

In theory, this would be `O(n*log(n))`, but Python `list.sort()` uses a clever sort algorithm called [timsort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which are designed to take advantage of runs in the data, such that it would sort a "mostly already sorted lists" -- such as concatenation of multiple sorted lists -- much faster than theory.

Answer (score 8):

The `heapq` module provides [a function to merge sorted iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) into a single sorted iterator.

```
from heapq import merge

merged = list(merge(a, b, c))
```

For example,

```
>>> a, b, c
([1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9])
>>> from heapq import merge
>>> list(merge(a, b, c))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> (a, b, c)
([1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9])
```

Comment: `heapq.merge()` is a great solution if you absolutely cannot make a copy of the list and has to use a generator, for example if your original lists are infinite iterators, but in practice, concatenate+sort is much, much faster than `heapq.merge()`. Try it with timeit.

Comment: True; I forgot that `sorted` is already good at sorting mostly sorted lists. I suspect `merge` would only be faster if you were merging many, many short lists, in which case the concatenation of the inputs would have many long sorted runs. (But even that might not be true; I don't feel like setting up a test :) )

Comment: I ended up using sorted and concatenating lists after seeing these comments. Should I move the green checkmark to the other answer?

Comment: Probably. `sorted` is probably better for lists specifically; one benefit of `merge` is that it is lazy: it produces an iterator in O(1) that only incurs the cost of merging as you iterate over the result, rather than producing a list immediately like `sorted` does.

Answer (score 2):

Combine them into a single list, and then sort that.

You can use a nested comprehension to flatten the lists as you iterate over them:

```
>>> a, b, c = [2, 4, 3], [1, 7, 5], [9, 6, 8]
>>> sorted(i for x in (a, b, c) for i in x)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or you can just add the lists together:

```
>>> sorted(a + b + c)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: while the elements in the different lists are directly comparable, they are, in reality, different in nature and require different treatments.

Comment: In your example they're lists of ints.  If they're something else that's not inherently comparable, use a `key` function to convert them into a form that is.  That part of the problem has nothing to do with the fact that they're separate lists.

Comment: Perhaps I COULD put them all in one list, even though they are different... list elements don't have to be of the same data type, do they?!

Comment: Nope, not at all.  If you have different data types it's a little odd that you'd be sorting them all together, and there's probably some better solution to whatever it is you're ultimately trying to do, but you haven't given any background on that so I can't suggest anything.